# Q: Proof of the linearity of expectation of random variable on page 38 of Shiryaev's Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is about the proof of the property of expectation of random variable:

$\mathbb{E}(a\xi+b\eta)=a\mathbb{E}\xi + b\mathbb{E}\eta.$

(finite probability space)

The proof on the book is as following:

Let $\xi=\sum_i x_i I(A_i)$ ($A_i=\{\omega \in \Omega:\xi(\omega)=x_i\}$) and $\eta=\sum_j y_j I(B_j)$.

Then
$$
a\xi+b\eta = a\sum_{i,j} x_i I(A_i \cap B_j) + b \sum_{i,j}y_j I(A_i \cap B_j)\\
=\sum_{i,j}(ax_i+by_j)I(A_i \cap B_j)
$$
**Questions 1**: I understand from first line of the equation to the second line intuitively (I actually listed every combination of i and j to check this), but I don't know the rigorous reasoning/derivation behind this.

(Continuing the proof)

and
$$
\mathbb{E}(a\xi+b\eta) = \sum_{i,j}(ax_i+by_j)P(A_i \cap B_j)\\
= \sum_i ax_i P(A_i) + \sum_j by_jP(B_j)\\
= \cdots = a\mathbb{E}\xi + b\mathbb{E}\eta
$$
**Question 2**: I don't understand this part: $\sum_{i,j}(ax_i + by_j)P(A_i \cap B_j) = \sum_i ax_iP(A_i) + \sum_j b y_j P(B_j)$. I feel like I am missing some intermediate steps here. My first thought was independence, but no that was not the case in here after give it a thought. How can this equality hold? And further, is there any condition under which it will fail?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q$1:$ Note that if $A\cap B=\varnothing$ then $I(A\cup B)=I(A)+I(B)$. Remember that $B_j\cap B_k=\varnothing$ for $j\neq k$ and $\cup_j B_j=\Omega$.
$$A_i=A_i\cap\Omega=A_i\cap\left(\cup_j B_j\right)=\cup_j(A_i\cap B_j)\\\sum_{i}x_iI(A_i)=\sum_{i}x_iI(\cup_j A_i\cap B_j)=\sum_{i}x_i\sum_jI(A_i\cap B_j)=\sum_{i,j}x_iI(A_i\cap B_j)$$

---

Q$2:$ Remembering $A_i\cap B_j$ and $A_i\cap B_k$ are disjoint for $j\neq k$ we see
$$
\sum_{i,j}x_iP(A_i\cap B_j)=\sum_i x_i\sum_j P(A_i\cap B_j)=\sum_i x_iP(\cup_j A_i\cap B_j)=\sum_i x_iP(A_i\cap(\cup_j B_j))\\=\sum_i x_iP(A_i\cap\Omega)=\sum_i x_iP(A_i)
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your fist answer is a little bit overkill at fist glance but then I saw your answer for the second question and now I understand why you used this approach and it also helped revealed a fundamental gap in my knowledge why I happened to have trouble with both the problems. P.S. For the first question, the first ``note'': if $A\cap B=\emptyset$ then $I(A\cup B)=I(A)+I(B)$ is not used or necessary, am I correct?

Comment: I used it in the part where I expand $I(\cup_j(A_i\cap B_j))=\sum_j I(A_i\cap B_j)$.

Answer (score 0):

For you first question, notice that the linear combination of finite sums is the finite sum of the linear combinations (in particular, there are no problems of convergence). That't it.

For your second question, notice that $\sum_j P(A_i\cap B_j)=P(A_i)$ and $\sum_i P(A_i\cap B_j)=P(B_j)$. Hence,
$$
\sum_{i,j}(ax_i+by_j)P(A_i \cap B_j)
= \sum_i ax_i P(A_i) + \sum_j by_jP(B_j).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your question. It is very sloppy of me that I didn't see this. For your second answer, it would be easier to understand the ``notice'' part  with the information @Jack's wasted life provided $B_j \cap B_k = \emptyset$ for $j \neq k$ and $(A_i \cap B_j) \cap  (A_i \cap B_k)=\emptyset$ for $j \neq k$ etc. I do appreciate the concise and simplicity.